# How to execute (call) a function of one class from another class?

Tags: java, bluej

I have two classes: "Add.java" and "Subtract.java". I want to use the result of the "addfn" method (of class **Add**) in "subfn" method (of class **Subtract**). How should I do it?

**Add.java**

```
public class Add
{
    public double a, b;
    public double addfn(double a, double b)
    {
     return (a+b);
    }
}
```

**Subtract.java**

```
public class Subtract
{
    double c, d;
    public double subfn(double d)
    {
        //
        //I want the "addfn" from class "Add" to accept the variables *a* and *b*
        //and then use "subfn" to use the result of "addfn" and assign it to *c*
        //
        Add obj1 = new Add();
        //Can I somehow access the "addfn" method here?
        c = a+b;               //and then assign its result to c here?
        return (c-d);
    }
}
```

I tried extending the class **Add** with the class **Subtract** like this:

```
public class Subtract extends Add
```

but Java simply assigned null values to *a* and *b* and thus *c* always became 0. It also did not enable me to access the "addfn" from the **Add** class.

How should I do it? Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for all your answers, but how can I specifically run a function from another class? And how can I run the two functions in immediate succession? Thanks, once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Add obj1 = new Add();
    c = obj1.addfn(obj1.a,obj1.b);
    return (c-d);
```

Comment: a and b variable exist in class Add

Comment: Here you go. He just asked about how to access the function, not the variables, but well...

Answer (score 0):

In your `Add` class, the line `public double a, b;` does nothing, since the `addfn` method only adds and returns the *method* arguments.

Since `Subtract` extends `Add`, you can work directly with addfn.

```
public double subfn(double d)
{
    c = addfn(5+10);
    return (c-d);
}
```